# The ted.com twitter widget?

Tags: api, twitter, social-networking, widget

On all the videos on ted, there is a widget thing with an inputfield that says tweet this (we'll add the url later) you put stuff in a box, it get's a tiny-url and get's pushed to facebook.

I'm trying to figure out what it's called. Does anyone have a clue?

example:
http://www.ted.com/talks/dan_phillips_creative_houses_from_reclaimed_stuff.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are using the service provided by [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com).  Looking at their site, they offer some stock sharing links, but also have an API for creating more advanced ones.

Comment: I've been snoping around there, but I can't seem to find the widget in question...

Comment: I don't think the widget is part of their standard set.  You'll need to use their API to create a similar widget:  http://www.addthis.com/help/api-overview